# Gesture Recognizer Blocking TouchesEnded

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, drawrect

In my app, a user taps three times and an angle is drawn with drawRect. This used to work perfectly until recently. I added a gesture recognizer to the parent view, a uiview, (the drawing occurs on a child of this view, a subclassed uiview). Now, when I tap, the drawing subclass doesn't call touches ended, but if I move my finger, touchesMoved gets called on the subclass. I know the issue is the gesture recognizer on the parent because when I remove it, everything goes back to normal. Why is this happening? Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue - I couldn't touch a button and I manage to sorted it with this code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
     // Replace to your view with button
    if ((touch.view isDescendantOfView:YOURVIEW))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Try replace text YOURVIEW with the view you have this issue with and remember to set up delegate to your gesture recogniser.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't work.. Found a different workaround, still don't know why touchesEnded doesn't get called.. My subclass is at the top of all the views.

EDIT: the issue was I set the gesture recognizer to self.primaryView.superview. THE SUPERVIEW was causing the issue. removed that and I was golden.